# NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType Not saving properly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject

The following method gets called in order to populate my `Core-Data` after `AFNetworking` fetches information from my app server.

The information seems to be perfectly working as when the table is updated I can see the new information being updated in the `UITableView`.

Now the problem that I have is that even tho I can see the information ( after it has been fetches from the server, stored into Core-data and refetches to display in my `UITableView`) If I then go and close my app and re open it, the information is not there anymore.

It seems as if the information is not persistent and the problem seems to be the thread. given that if I remove the thread option in my method everything works fine.

What am I missing?? I have tried most things that I came across but I can't seem to find a solution.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *childContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]
                                        initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
childContext.parentContext = managedObjectContext;
myModel.context = childContext;


   [childContext performBlock:^{
// ... Lots Controller logic code that then calls the class myModel where all my Core-Data save methods are

    // Sort Wall Pictures
                    if ( [dataHolder[@"verb"] isEqualToString:@"addWallPicture"] ) {
                        data = @{  @"resourceID":dataHolder[@"_id"][@"$id"],
                                   @"resourceName":dataHolder[@"details"][@"resourceName"],
                                   @"author":@{ @"id":dataHolder[@"userId"][@"$id"],
                                                @"username":dataHolder[@"details"][@"authorName"] },
                                   @"likesNumber":@0,
                                   @"likesPeople":@[]
                                   };

                        [myModel saveSocialWall:data date:date verb:dataHolder[@"verb"] code:dataHolder[@"_id"][@"$id"] myUser:myUser];
                        continue;
                    }
[childContext save:&error];
}];
```

Comment: Do you save the main context as well? Saving the child context saves only to the main context, and saving the main context saves to the store file.

Comment: How can I save the main context after the thread has been completed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to save the main context as well at some point, e.g. after saving the child context.

Saving the child context saves only to the main context, and saving the main context saves to the store file.

Like this (written on the phone, there will
be syntax errors):

```
// ...
[childContext save:&error];
[mainContext performBlock:^{
    [mainContext save:&error];
}];
```

In **Swift 2.0** that would be:

```
do {
    try childContext.save()
    mainContext.performBlock { 
        do {
            try mainContext.save()
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print("Could not save main context: \(err.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
} catch let err as NSError {
    print("Could not save private context: \(err.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: How can I ignore the changes made by childContext. Because if I don't want to save the childContext and I do some other operations on Core Data and save on mainContext, will the earlier childContext will be saved as well?

Comment: @Vacca: Saving the *child* context merges its changes up to the parent (the main context). Saving the *main* context saves to the persistent store (if it does not have another parent), but does not modify the child context.

Comment: No I am saying what if I don't save my RootParentContext (Main) when I saved my Child Context, due to some conditions I have to ignore the changes. After, on next hop of saving, if some operations try to save on Root (main), will the previous Child Context changes will be saved or ignored?

Comment: Does this mean that, saving a child context will keep the data locally and if we kill the app without saving the main context, nothing will be saved in the database?