# Core Data Private Queue not saving

Tags: objective-c, core-data, concurrency

I've created a fairly simple stack where I have a Master context on a private queue that has the persistent store attached.  The problem I'm having is that changes are stopping at the main queue.  They don't seem to be passed up to the private queue to write the changes to disk.

I create the master context:

```
        _masterContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

        _masterContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:objectModel];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSDictionary *migrationOptions = @{ NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES };
        [_masterContext.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                                configuration:nil
                                                                          URL:databaseURL
                                                                      options:migrationOptions
                                                                        error:&error];
        if (error){
            NSLog(@"Core Data Error: %@", error.description);
        }
```

I then create a "main" context on that operates on the main queue and use it for interacting with the rest of the app:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = ({
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        context.parentContext = _masterContext;
        context;
    });
```

Finally, there is another private concurrency queue created to for syncing operations:

```
    CSCoreDataSyncEngine *syncEngine = [[CSCoreDataSyncEngine alloc] initWithParentContext:mainContext
                                                                               usingServer:[CSRemoteServerV1 new]
                                                                                   adapter:[CSServerCoreDataAdapterV1 new]];

    CSModelManager *modelManager = [[CSModelManager alloc] initWithDataStore:mainContext syncEngine:syncEngine];
```

Of note: the `modelManager` *uses* the main queue.  The `syncEngine` will create it's own private concurrency queue to perform syncing operations.

If I remove the "master" context and attach the persistent store to the "main" context, then the changes are saved to disk.  But so long as I have the "master" context as the top parent, the changes won't be written to disk.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Do you explicitly `save` the master context? Saving a child context saves the changes to its immediate parent context. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19328394/nsprivatequeueconcurrencytype-not-saving-properly.

Comment: Yep, I wasn't saving on the master context.  Thanks!