# CoreData thread safe object context save

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a tableview that is populated using a fetched results controller. It automatically updates when the data changes.

I also have a background thread processing files and when I trigger a save I want this tableview to update. Currently I'm getting some strange errors and I'm not sure if this is the correct way to set it all up.

I modified my main managedObjectContext in my appdelegate to be a main queue type:

```
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if coordinator == nil {
        return nil
    }
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()
```

Then in my thread I'm creating private queue type:

```
let mainManagedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
let privateManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
privateManagedObjectContext!.parentContext = mainManagedObjectContext
```

I then do a save later in my thread like this:

```
 do {
      try self.privateManagedObjectContext!.save()
 } catch {
 }
```

This does work.. however its not persistent and I think I need to do a save on the managedObjectContext. Is this correct?

**UPDATE**

Its now working.. I just wasn't saving to the main context here is my code if anyone gets stuck:

```
do {
    try self.privateManagedObjectContext!.save()
} catch {
    print("can't save to private context")
}

mainManagedObjectContext?.performBlock({
    do{
        try self.mainManagedObjectContext!.save()
    } catch {
        print("can't save to main context")
    }
})
```

Comment: That is correct. Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: Yes, it works... but when I restart the app the changes I made to the private managed object context haven't been saved

Comment: Did you save the *main* context? (Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19328394/nsprivatequeueconcurrencytype-not-saving-properly, which is in Objective-C, but probably the same issue).

Comment: ahhh ha... the missing piece to the puzzle. Its now working. thanks!