# iOS CoreData with Network and multiple threads

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, networking, core-data

This is question about understanding of approach working with UI, CoreData and Network in the same time. Some words about my App: it's simple list of tasks stored by CoreData and retrieve/send changes over TCP protocol.
List of tasks present as `UIViewController` and delegate `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`.

I initialized CoreData stack in `AppDelegate` and passed instance of managedObjectContext to my `UIViewController`:

```
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()
```

I carefully read [about CoreData Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH24-SW1) and noticed that I shouldn't pass `NSManagedObject` instances between threads and should use private MOCs out of main thread. So in my singletone network object (which also has link to main `managedObjectContext`) when when Application has recieved some data that I need to store I actually do something like this:

```
func processObject(objectID: NSManagedObjectID, callback: () -> Void){
    let privateMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
    privateMOC.parentContext = self.managedObjectContext
    privateMOC.performBlock {
        if let object = privateMOC.objectWithID(objectID) as? MyItem {
            object.someProperty = "SomeValue"
            do {
                try privateMOC.save()
            } catch { /* Something to say our user */ }
        }
    }
}
```

I've got some issues with this approach but the main question is: should I create on every network event new private MOC and to do my actions throw `performBlock` or it'll be enough one private MOC for whole Network object?

Comment: And actually I noticed that everything starts working only after I'll saving both of contexts like it [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19328477/2417790). Is it even legal?

Comment: For those who want to check if their private MOCs are accessible from correct threads [read this awesome article](https://pawanpoudel.svbtle.com/fixing-core-data-concurrency-violations).

Answer (score 0):

You'll want one global MOC, as there is only one "bank" of CoreData. I ran into this issue a while back, and yes, you could use multiple private instances, but you'll have to make sure two threads or events don't access or change data at the same time as the other. You could use semaphores to alleviate this, but to be simple and concise, I'd use one global MOC.

Comment: I'd like idea to use the only one MOC but main problem here is that I should access to this MOC only from one thread and it's not so easy (not sure even possible) in my architecture. I read somewhere that MOC with children can resolve this conflicts automatically and I can't understand any benefits of such approach if I should take care about it manually.